# Fill item Id in form based on a combo box that selects item name. MS-Access

Tags: ms-access

1. I have a Sales form that contains the **ItemSoldID** field.
2. It was difficult to write **itemSoldID** for every item by memory because new items are frequently added and the list has reached to More than 100 Items. It is difficult to remember id number for every item.
3. I want to make a combo box. That should Choose Item Name in the box and the ItemSoldID gets autofilled based on the Selection.
4. I tried dlookup on gotfocus property of ItemSoldID but i am new to access. Something is wrong.
5. Please Help............

Comment: This looks like an application question not a database question.  If it gets closed you might try https://superuser.com/

Comment: Thanks. Got the solution on superuser.com. it was to use the same combo box but just save the value to the itemsold id instead ot saving in a variable.